# PDO session storing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to build this simple login/signup/logout system. I am trying to add a session so that users who are not logged in can't navigate to home.php but even though I added the `session_start()` and stored the email with `$_SESSION['user_email'] = $email_log`.

I still am navigating to home.php without logging in.

Login code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_log']) == 1) {
        $stmt_lg = $conn->prepare("SELECT  id, email, password FROM user WHERE email = :email_log AND password = :password_log");
        $stmt_lg->bindParam(":email_log", $email_log);
        $stmt_lg->bindParam(":password_log", $password_log);
        $stmt_lg->execute();
        $user = $stmt_lg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($user === false) {
            echo "<script>alert('Username or password is incorrect.');</script>";
        } else {                
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['email_log'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

                header('Location: home.php');
                exit;

            }
        }
```

home.php:

```
$sess = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$sess_ch = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :user_email");
$sess_ch->bindParam(":user_email", $sess);
$sess_ch->execute();
$ses = $sess_ch->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($ses === 1) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
}
```

logout.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$pass2 = $_POST['password2'];
$email_log = $_POST['email_log'];
$password_log = $_POST['password_log'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=program", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "<script>alert('Connected successfully');</script>"; 

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) == 1) {
            $stmt_ch = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
            $stmt_ch->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $stmt_ch->execute();

            if ($stmt_ch->rowCount() === 1) {
                echo "<script>alert('Username already taken.');</script>";
            } else {
                $stmt_re = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :password)");
                $stmt_re->bindParam(":name", $name);
                $stmt_re->bindParam(":email", $email);
                $stmt_re->bindParam(":password", $pass);
                $stmt_re->execute();
                echo "<script>alert('Account was successfully registerd.');</script>";
            }
        }

    if (isset($_POST['submit_log']) == 1) {
            $stmt_lg = $conn->prepare("SELECT  id, email, password FROM user WHERE email = :email_log AND password = :password_log");
            $stmt_lg->bindParam(":email_log", $email_log);
            $stmt_lg->bindParam(":password_log", $password_log);
            $stmt_lg->execute();
            $user = $stmt_lg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($user === false) {
                echo "<script>alert('Username or password is incorrect.');</script>";
            } else {                
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['email_log'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

                    header('Location: home.php');
                    exit;

                }
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

?>
```

Comment: Please check my answer.I have update it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of your code since your `$ses` will return true and false on failure, furthermore you only need to check the session variable if it has been set or not.

```
if ($ses === 1) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
}
```

At the top your home.php check if `$_SESSION['user_email']` is not set then if its not set, redirect to other page

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){
  //Redirect to other page since the user_email is not set
  //Let just say you will redirect to index.php file
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: it also redirects me back to index.php everytime I login

Comment: @Raymond I have udpate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect: `$ses = $sess_ch->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` as setFetchMode returns a bool. Thus if you were to `var_dump($ses);` you would likely find that `$ses === true`, which is not identical with 1; thus your if statement returns false.

Instead, use:

```
$ses = $sess_ch->fetch();
if(!$ses){ header('Location: index.php'); }
```

Edit for clarification: I was talking about in home.php

Comment: now it's keeps redirecting back to index.php everytime I login

Comment: in `home.php` comment out the redirect line, and `var_dump($ses);` as well as `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: All values gave null even though I stored them inside the login?

Comment: does `home.php` start with `session_start();` at the top?

Comment: please update home.php with all code prior to the redirect. Leave the var_dumps in the code as their location may be relevant.

Comment: I fixed by changing `$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['email_log'];` to `$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['email'];` but now session_destroy is not working

Comment: dunno how to fix session_destroy bugs. You'll have to google that one.

Comment: Update. Forgot to add `session_start();` at logout.php. Thank you for the help.